# URL encoding removed when opening link in iOS mail app

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, url-encoding

The iOS app that I'm working on programmatically sends an email containing a URL. The contents of the URL are being percent-encoded, but when the URL contains '%26' (the encoding for &), opening the link in the Mail app (which then redirects to Safari) seems to replace the encoding with '&', which is causing me problems.

For example, if my app was emailing the URL www.stackoverflow.com/asdf%26asdf, opening the link would load the URL www.stackoverflow.com/asdf&asdf in Safari. Opening the same link on my computer doesn't seem to have any problems. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried sending the URL in html format? Means constructing a html email.

Comment: @bikram990 The email is already HTML formatted, sadly

Comment: How you are representing the URL in HTML? are you using something like `<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>` ?